# How do I stop/disable PITR and safely clean WAL segments?

Tags: postgresql

Our production server is running PostgreSQL v8.2.3 on CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

We've setup PITR in our production server.  For some reasons, after setting up PITR, we're not able to manage and maintain it.  Eventually, our WAL archive drive (secondary drive) has become full (100% use) and additional WAL archive segments that are to be archived got accumulated in pg_xlog/ directory itself (which is available in primary drive)

**PITR SETUP DETAILS**

There are 2 drives:

1. Primary drive (*pgsql/data/* directory resides) is 400 GB.
2. Secondary drive (WAL archives) is 300 GB.  All WAL archives are written to this secondary drive.

Now, we've decided to stop/disable PITR.

My question is, in this situation, how do I stop/disable PITR and *safely* clean up all WAL segments from both the drives?

What are the recommended/suggested ways? Experts advice/idea/suggestion on this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

To stop the archiving in 8.2, you set `archive_command` to empty (`''`) and restart the server.  The data directory should clean itself up.  The archives on your secondary drive you can just throw away.

Comment: I understand that setting `archive_command` to empty (`''`) will stop/disable archiving.  But will this also automatically remove/delete all accumulated *old* WAL files from pg_xlog/ directory?

Answer (score 0):

Set archive_command='/bin/true' and reload pg.
Or set archive_mode=Off and restart pg.